# Viewing 2017 Solar Eclipse - How important is it to be in the center(blue line)?

Tags: solar-eclipse

I'm viewing the 2017 Solar Eclipse in Graham County, NC.  How important is it to be in the center(blue line)?

It is almost entirely national forest there so it would be fairly easy to get to assuming I can park somewhere.

http://xjubier.free.fr/en/site_pages/solar_eclipses/TSE_2017_GoogleMapFull.html

Comment: http://www.eclipse2017.org/2017/communities/states/NC/Robbinsville_966.htm may or may not be helpful. As the event approaches, your city/county official websites may start posting more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see a total solar eclipse, you just need to be between the two red lines on that map.  As long as you're within there, what we call the "path of totality", you will be able to see a total solar eclipse.

If you are outside of the red lines, you will only see a partial solar eclipse.  [This map](https://www.greatamericaneclipse.com/nation/) shows what percentage of the sun will be covered the further north or south you are of the line.

Graham County is entirely within the path of totality, so you should see a total solar eclipse.  If you're planning to travel, however, it might be too late.  Most campgrounds and hotels within the path are already full.  If you're already within the path of totality, my recommendation would be to stay put.  Travelling on that day, or even that week, will be difficult.

The center of the path of totality will offer the longest viewing for the eclipse.  The further from the center, the shorter it will last.  [The aforementioned map](https://www.greatamericaneclipse.com/nation/) shows timings at different distances from the center.  Notice that it also helps to be close longitudinally as well as latitudinally (that may not be a word).

Comment: My grandparents live in Graham county so I have a room.  So it doesn't matter how close I am to the blue line yes?

Comment: That is correct.  As long as you are between those red lines, the eclipse will be total.

Comment: What about the length of the solar eclipse will it be longer closer to the blue line?  I have a GPS device that we use for hiking if we were trying to get really close.

Comment: [This map](https://www.greatamericaneclipse.com/nation/) shows how long the solar eclipse will last in different areas.  The closer you are to the very center, both in latitude and longitude, the longer it will last.  However, the difference will be a matter of a few seconds, nothing major.

Comment: Totality doesn't last very long for this eclipse, so the closer to the centre line the better.  If you are close to the edge, totality will last only a few seconds.  For best results try to get within a few miles of the centre line.

Comment: Based on @William's location, I think he's within the 2+ minute zone.